# How to FORCE docker to bind to ip4 addresses?

Tags: docker

How do I **FORCE** docker to bind to ip4 addresses for port forwarding, **DISREGARDING** any claims by the docker team that those binds that show as ipv6-only in `netstat` somehow *should* work just fine and I shouldn't need to do anything else?

I don't trust the automagic. What I can **see with my own eyes** is that:

- I can connect to the mysql server from inside the container, so it is obviously running
- I cannot connect to the mysql server in the container from the host, even though I have quintuply checked that I am trying to connect to the correct port
- docker-proxy is actually listening on this port, but only on an ipv6 address

I am in the middle of debugging a connection issue, and I am trying to definitively eliminate possible causes one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [specifying host's IP](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports) in port binding, eg.

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 mysql:latest
```